# Can I create a forward for the old link?

Tags: ee

I updated the initiatives on our website to say 2016 and now all the old links  to our current initiatives that were posted or shared (web, email, social etc.) in the last year is now broken. How cab I remedy this? Can I create a forward for the old link? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a variety of ways to make this happen. To give you the absolute best answer, you'd really need to give more information on your EE setup in general. It would've helped if you had given an example of the URL you need redirected as well. Here is a simple solution.

You'll need to edit your `.htaccess` file. It lives in the web root of your server. **Warning:** If you are not a developer, it is recommended that you get someone more tech savvy to do this for you. One mistake in this file will render your website unavailable until it is fixed.

If you have an example URL, such as `www.example.com/initiatives/2015/`, and you want to permanently redirect it to `www.example.com/initiatives/2016/`, under most cases a RedirectMatch rule will work. Here's an example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/initiatives/2015/?$ http://www.example.com/initiatives/2016/
```

This will match URN's that match `/initiatives/2015/` and permanently redirect them to `http://www.example.com/initiatives/2016/` . The match will be permanent (`301`) and will be case-insensitive ( `(?i)`, so `/INITiatives/2015/` would also redirect). You can add this line at the end of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Or use Detour Pro https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro